How to change default options for /proc mount in Ubuntu Linux
I have a virtual private server hosted in the cloud running Ubuntu 22.04, and I need to change the options with which /proc is mounted. Currently it gets mounted with the hidepid=2 option. However, this setting is incompatible with the Java virtual machine that DB2 uses to execute stored procedures written in Java, causing invocations of those procedures to fail. I can correct the problem by remounting with hidepid=0, but there are two problems with that. One, after a few minutes /proc gets remounted automatically with hidepid=2, and two, whenever the server is rebooted it gets mounted with hidepid=2. How can I get this changed permanently? (Note: The mount definition is not found in /etc/fstab, so it's not just a matter of changing something there.)

Does adding an entry to /etc/fstab help?

I believe I tried this once and it didn't have an effect, but since that post specifically identifies it as working I will try it again.

Try sudo grep -r hidepid /etc/systemd/ /run/systemd/ /usr/lib/systemd/. Is there any output?

I get grep: /usr/lib/systemd/systemd: binary file matches

Next hypothesis: sudo grep -r hidepid /etc/cron*.

Nothing from that one.

Anything you set for a /proc mount in /etc/fstab should apply starting next boot: systemd takes care of the "API filesystems" and mounts them automatically on start with defaults, if the filesystems are not specified in /etc/fstab.
https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/APIFileSystems/

Not working. I tried both
proc /proc proc defaults,hidepid=0 0 0
and
proc /proc proc rw,relatime,hidepid=0 0 0
and either way hidepid always ends up =2.

darn. Then that sounds like you have an additional service that remounts the /proc file system periodically.

This article just popped up today, but it is of course of no help because there is no line for mounting /proc in /etc/fstab. https://usercomp.com/news/1409742/change-proc-mount-options-in-ubuntu

@KevinRahe that article seems ChatGPT. Anyways,as I said, if you add that line, it should override systemd's defaults.

This article added one more important clue, which is to include remount in the options, as in proc /proc proc remount,rw,relatime,hidepid=0 0 0. Now with that in /etc/fstab I can do a mount -o remount /proc and it picks up the change. The maddening part, however, is that it won't pick up this change on a reboot! I have to open a console after booting and do the remount in a console. On top of that, whatever is resetting the mount options every few minutes continues to run, so that it sets hidepid=2 again. !!!

Actually, I just did another test, and adding remount in fstab really doesn't have any effect. I can do the mount -o remount /proc without it in there and get the same effect.

yeah as said, that article was written by ChatGPT, not someone with understanding

Sheesh, what a waste of resources and everyone's time. It's like some search engine saw me searching desperately for something, then put up a web page that seems like exactly what I'm looking for, which ended up being of no actual help. Bizarre.
